# Creating a new batch class

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, schedulebatch

Need help to creating batch class.I have tried below Batch class.when am trying to save the same class getting error like below.

> " Compile Error: Variable does not exist: newmap at line 13 column
>   127    "

Please check below class which i have tried and correct me where i made the mistakes.

Class:

```
global class PartnerGroupCountBatch implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>{
      String query ='';
        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //query = 'Select id,AccountId,UserorGroupId,UserorGroup.Name from AccountShare Where AccountId IN :newmap.keyset() and UserorGroup.Name Like:s';
        query = 'Select id,AccountId,UserorGroupId,UserorGroup.Name from AccountShare';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }   
      global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> accts) 
      {     
        Map<Id,List<AccountShare>> Map_list_AccntShare = new Map<Id,List<AccountShare>>();
        string mystring = 'P-'; 
        string s='%' +mystring + '%';
        for(AccountShare AcntShare :[Select id,AccountId,UserorGroupId,UserorGroup.Name from AccountShare Where AccountId IN :newmap.keyset() and UserorGroup.Name Like:s])
        {
            if(Map_list_AccntShare!=null && Map_list_AccntShare.containsKey(AcntShare.AccountId))
            Map_list_AccntShare.get(AcntShare.AccountId).add(AcntShare);
            else{
                List<AccountShare> i = new  List<AccountShare>();
                i.add(AcntShare);
                Map_list_AccntShare.put(AcntShare.AccountId,i);
            }
        }
        for(Account acc:accts)
        {
            if(Map_list_AccntShare.get(acc.id)!=null)
            acc.PartnerGroup_Count__c=Map_list_AccntShare.get(acc.id).size();
        }
     }
     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
     }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of problems in your code. As the error says, you're using a variable that doen't exist: `newMap`. Also, you're querying `AccountShare` objects, but in your execute method you set as parameter a list of `Account` objects. That's not possible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please do not remove all of the code once you get a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's literally no other mention of "newmap" in your code. Most likely, you meant "accts" instead, which is the parameter passed to you by the Batchable interface for the current execute transaction. By the way, your code would be significantly more efficient if you just used [AggregateResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) instead.

---

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    for(Account record: scope) {
        record.PartnerGroup_Count__c = 0;
    }
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(scope);
    for(AggregateResult result: [
        SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) sum
        FROM AccountShare 
        WHERE AccountId = :scope AND UserOrGroup.Name LIKE '%P-%'
        GROUP BY AccountId]) {
        accounts.get(
           (Id)result.get('Id')
        ).PartnerGroup_Count__c = (Decimal)result.get('sum');
    }
    update scope;
}
```

---

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you're querying AccountShare records, when you really meant to query Account records instead.

Comment: He's also querying `AccountShare` objects and getting `Account` objects as parameter of its `execute` method.

Comment: @MartinLezer I meant to include that. Still doing some edits.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you so much your valid help.  Hear am facing one problem whene we are trying to run my batch some of the accounts are failing with error like                                                                                        System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 400 with id 001C000000rgu14IAA; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Account Update: Hierarchy with Large number of nodes cannot be bulkified.:  Can you please help me to how to avoid this type of exceptions  Thanks

Comment: @HariSfdc it sounds like you need to reduce the number of records being processed. Try reducing the batch size and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Yes,  i have redueced the size and tried.getting same exceptions.Not sure how i can avoid them.  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a validation rule or custom error. Search your metadata for that message